# Excel - if cell contains (text) then paste (new text) - Macro required please

Tags: excel, vba

I have a big list of products and want to be have a quick way of categorising them. So in column A I have lots of products e.g. tools. Rather than typing the category structure each time next to them (Tools>Hammers) I want a quick way to search column A for all cells containing 'Hammer' and paste in column B 'Tools>Hammer'.

i'm sure there is an easy way, anyone know what it is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, as the comment mentioned, I don't think you need a Macro for this.

Create a separate sheet(I always name mine "code"), and list the products in column A and the category in column B. This is what you will reference with VLOOKUP().

With this table created, the code in your category table will be something like

```
=CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(Product,Code!A:B,2,FALSE),">",Product)
```

Which, if you've done it properly, should return "Tools>Hammer". I should note that "product" is the cell which contains the name of your product, if that isn't clear. There may be some issues with quotes, but I think that my code has it correct. You can also extend a VLOOKUP to refer to a lot of data, if that helps you later in your project. So you could include part #'s, etc.

Hope this helps, it's much easier than doing a macro.